# How to modify query param in webflux filter

Tags: filter, spring-webflux

So any ideal how to modify query param in webflux filter, this code didn't work;

```
public class MyFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

        // didn't work, throw UnSupportOperationException
        //request.getQueryParams().add("key1", "value1"); 

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to call `mutate` before changing the request

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how you can modify the query param but the reason why you are not able to modify the params through the method getQueryParams() is because it returns a read only map. Check this link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServerHttpRequest.html#getQueryParams--

Answer (score 0):

As @Prakher Jindal explained request.getQueryParams() returns a read-only map,
but you can add query params by writing a filter like this:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Optional;
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR;

@Component
public class MyRewriteGatewayFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<MyRewriteGatewayFilter.Config> {

    public SecurityRewriteGatewayFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> {
            Optional.of(exchange)
                    .map(e -> (URI) e.getAttribute(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR))
                    .map(URI::toString)
                    .map(uri -> uri + "?key=" + "value")
                    .map(UriComponentsBuilder::fromUriString)
                    .map(UriComponentsBuilder::build)
                    .map(UriComponents::toUri)
                    .ifPresent(u -> exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, u));

            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().build());
        }
                , RouteToRequestUrlFilter.ROUTE_TO_URL_FILTER_ORDER + 1);
    }


    @Data
    public static class Config {
    }
}
```

Since this filter is not a global filter, make sure to add this to your application.yml file for the
routes on which you want to apply it. Something like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: my-routes
          uri: http://localhost:8082
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
          filters:
            - name: MyRewriteGatewayFilter
```